# why is repaint() not working?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to add the buttons to the centerPanel that I created, then add that panel to the main center borderlayout. for some reason though my tab will not repaint anymore. It worked fine a while ago when I had the DrawFieldsListener class in the same class file as the MagicSquare, but nothing in the code has changed from my splitting them into two class files. So i really don't know what is going on. When it did repaint before, it would also take a long time. Any help? thanks!

All source for the project is on GitHub if it is easier to read and understand there: https://github.com/andrefecto/Academic-Convivium-Project

MagicSquare Class:

```
package magicSquare;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class MagicSquare extends JPanel {
    JLabel sizeLabel = new JLabel("Enter A Square Size: ");
    JButton setSize;
    static JButton calculate;
    static JButton reset;
    static JTextField squareSize;
    static JTextField field;

    public static ArrayList<JTextField> inputFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
    public static ArrayList<Integer> inputs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public static ArrayList<Integer> totals = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static int squared = 0;
    public static int square = 0;

    public static JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
    public static JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();

    public MagicSquare (){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel subPanel = new JPanel();

        subPanel.add(sizeLabel);

        squareSize = new JTextField();
        squareSize.setColumns(6);
        subPanel.add(squareSize);

        setSize = new JButton("Enter");
        subPanel.add(setSize);
        setSize.addActionListener(new DrawFieldsListener());

        add(subPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(new DrawFieldsListener(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

my DrawFieldsListener class:

```
package magicSquare;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

class DrawFieldsListener extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    int square = MagicSquare.square;
    int squared = MagicSquare.squared;
    JPanel centerPanel = MagicSquare.centerPanel;
    JTextField squareSize = MagicSquare.squareSize;
    JTextField field = MagicSquare.field;
    ArrayList<JTextField> inputFields = MagicSquare.inputFields;
    JButton calculate = MagicSquare.calculate;
    JButton reset = MagicSquare.reset;
    JPanel bottomPanel = MagicSquare.bottomPanel;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        square = Integer.parseInt(squareSize.getText());
        squared = square*square;

        centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(square, square));

        for(int i = 0; i < squared; i++){
            field = new JTextField();
            field.setColumns(3);
            inputFields.add(field);
            centerPanel.add(inputFields.get(i));
            System.out.println("DRAWING");
        }

        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        System.out.println("ADDING ADDITINOAL BUTTONS");
        additionalButtons();
        System.out.println("ADDED ADDITINOAL BUTTONS");
        System.out.println("REPAINTING");
        repaint();
        System.out.println("REPAINTED");
    }
    public void additionalButtons(){
        calculate = new JButton("Calculate");
        reset = new JButton("Reset");

        bottomPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        bottomPanel.add(reset);
        bottomPanel.add(calculate);

        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        calculate.addActionListener(new CalculateListener());
        reset.addActionListener(new ResetListener());
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: `public static JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();` scares the willies out me...especially when you do `JPanel centerPanel = MagicSquare.centerPanel;`?!

Comment: BTW - `static` is typically not the solution to whatever problem you are trying to solve..

Comment: You're creating two instances of `DrawFieldsListener`, which will screw with your use of `static`, one is been used as the `ActionLIstener` one is on the screen...when the `ActionListener` is triggered, who knows what is been updated...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I see your comment below, sorry.

Comment: @AndréFecteau It's scary because your code is now 10x as difficult to reason about, both for us and for you. This is why at least some level of encapsulation is generally a good thing, because we can tell where objects are visible and who can use them. `public static` means we have no idea who everybody is that accesses it, and chances are you probably can't remember either.

Comment: @Radiodef That makes sense, thank you. I assume that is a OOP practice?

Comment: That's correct. When we use static variables, the entire program can touch those variables *anywhere*. When we use instance variables (perhaps passed in through a constructor), the scope is much more narrow and we can follow an exact chain of events that leads to some access.

Comment: @Radiodef Ok thank you. I am pretty new to OOP, I missed out on the intro to Java course and was placed right into this current Object Oriented Programming with Java course, so I am trying to learn OOP as I go along. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. We understand: Java throws a lot of stuff at you all at once. `static` variables aren't inherently bad, but when you use global state to do things like pass values, understanding the program requires understanding everything all at once. As a program gets even moderately larger, it becomes too much to fit in your head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Mistake #1

```
public static JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
```

Followed by...

```
class DrawFieldsListener extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    //...
    JPanel centerPanel = MagicSquare.centerPanel;
```

`static` is not a cross object communication mechanism...and now I have no idea who is suppose to be responsible for managing the `centerPanel`...

Remember, `static` is not your friend, beware of how it is used

## Mistake #2

```
setSize.addActionListener(new DrawFieldsListener());

add(subPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(new DrawFieldsListener(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

You are creating two instances of `DrawFieldsListener` (which is a panel), one is acting as the `ActionListener` and one is acting as the view, but which one is actually housing `MagicSquare.centerPanel` as a component can only have one parent...

## Mistake #3

Not revalidating the container after you have changed it...

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        square = Integer.parseInt(squareSize.getText());
        squared = square * square;

        centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(square, square));

        for (int i = 0; i < squared; i++) {
            field = new JTextField();
            field.setColumns(3);
            inputFields.add(field);
            centerPanel.add(inputFields.get(i));
            System.out.println("DRAWING");
        }

        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        System.out.println("ADDING ADDITINOAL BUTTONS");
        additionalButtons();
        System.out.println("ADDED ADDITINOAL BUTTONS");
        System.out.println("REPAINTING");
        revalidate();
        repaint();
        System.out.println("REPAINTED");
    }
```

Swing is lazy when it comes to container management, it assumes that you will want to do a number of adds or removes, so it won't update the container hierarchy layout until you ask it to, as the operation can be expensive

## A better solution...

Isolate responsibility and provide information to your objects in a de-coupled manner.

For example, the `DrawFieldsListener` shouldn't care about `MagicSquare`, but should provide a means by which "some body" can tell it how many squares it should create.

[image: Squares]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class MagicSquare extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new MagicSquare());
                frame.setSize(400, 400);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    JLabel sizeLabel = new JLabel("Enter A Square Size: ");
    JButton setSize;
    private JSpinner squareSize;
    JTextField field;

    public MagicSquare() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel subPanel = new JPanel();

        subPanel.add(sizeLabel);

        squareSize = new JSpinner();
        subPanel.add(squareSize);

        setSize = new JButton("Enter");
        subPanel.add(setSize);
        DrawFieldsListener dfl = new DrawFieldsListener();
        setSize.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int gridSize = (int) squareSize.getValue();
                dfl.makeGrid(gridSize);
            }
        });

        add(subPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(dfl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    class DrawFieldsListener extends JPanel {

        private JButton calculate;
        private JButton reset;

        private ArrayList<JTextField> inputFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
        private ArrayList<Integer> inputs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        private ArrayList<Integer> totals = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        private int squared = 0;
        private int square = 0;

        private JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        private JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();

        public void makeGrid(int gridSize) {
            square = gridSize;
            squared = square * square;

            centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(square, square));

            for (int i = 0; i < squared; i++) {
                field = new JTextField();
                field.setColumns(3);
                inputFields.add(field);
                centerPanel.add(inputFields.get(i));
                System.out.println("DRAWING");
            }

            add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            System.out.println("ADDING ADDITINOAL BUTTONS");
            additionalButtons();
            System.out.println("ADDED ADDITINOAL BUTTONS");
            System.out.println("REPAINTING");
            revalidate();
            repaint();
            System.out.println("REPAINTED");
        }

        public void additionalButtons() {
            calculate = new JButton("Calculate");
            reset = new JButton("Reset");

            bottomPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
            bottomPanel.add(reset);
            bottomPanel.add(calculate);

            add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

//          calculate.addActionListener(new CalculateListener());
//          reset.addActionListener(new ResetListener());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do not call the centerPanel static then I am not able to add any Textfields to it. Also if I do not make the centerPanel in the MagicSquare class I am not able to add it to the current showing borderlayout center. How would I be able to remove the static? I appreciate the help, thank you!

Comment: @AndréFecteau Why does `MagicSquare` need access to any of those static fields?  Why does `DrawFieldsListener` need access to any of those fields?  Focus on confining responsibility to the object that really should be responsible for those fields.  Use methods to and callbacks to transfer information between objects

Comment: Objects should be greedy and protective, they should shield information from modification and simply provide methods (as gate keeps) so that the fields are modified only in away which the object wants them to be...that's one of the points of OO

Comment: When i try and run the code you have provided I get a bunch of errors. As well as the problem with including a main method is that I already have one in another class file. This Magic Square game is just one game inside of a Tabbed window. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: *"When i try and run the code you have provided I get a bunch of errors"* - Well, it runs perfectly fine for me, as can be seen by the runnable example and animation...

Comment: Ok I got it, I had to put it in a new project. Thank you! I will use this code to fix up my tab. Thanks!